# testing login api with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

how to test this Api and get 100% score of testing coverage?

```
const login = async (email, password) => {
  axios
    .post('https://conduit.productionready.io/api/users/login', {
      user: {
        email,
        password,
      },
    })
    .then((response) => response);
};
```

Comment: What's your current test and coverage? There's only one path through it, no branching logic, so getting full coverage shouldn't be a problem. The function has some obvious problems, though - it's `async` but doesn't `await` anything, uses `.then` (pointlessly, `.then((value) => value)` is a no-op) despite being `async` and *doesn't return anything*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is relatively simple : one path, no branching logic, one external call.

All your function do is calling an endpoint through `axios.post`.

login.js

```js
export const login = async (email, password) => {
  /*
   * Notice that I added the 'await', else 'async' is useless.
   * Else you can directly return the axios.post method.
   */
  await axios
    .post('https://conduit.productionready.io/api/users/login', {
      user: {
        email,
        password,
      },
    })
    .then((response) => response); // This line is also useless for the moment
};
```

login.spec.js

```js
import { login } from './login';

// Mock axios, else you will really request the endpoint
jest.mock('axios');
import axios from 'axios';

describe('Login tests', () => {
  describe('login function', () => {
    const email = 'test@test.com';
    const password = 'password';

    beforeEach(() => {
      /*
       * Not necessary for the moment, but will be useful
       * to test successful & error response
       */
      axios.post.mockResolvedValue({});
    });

    it('should call endpoint with given email & password', async () => {
      await login(email, password);
      expect(axios.post).toBeCalledWith(
        'https://conduit.productionready.io/api/users/login',
        { user: { email, password } },
      );
    });
  });
});
```

Notice that you could greatly improve your login function by returning something and handling error with an Authentication Error. Your tests would be more significant :

errors.js

```js
export class DefaultError extends Error {
  static STATUS_CODE = 500; // You can change it, it depends how you use it
  name = 'DefaultError';

  constructor() {
    super('Default error, add what you want');
  }
}

export class AuthenticationError extends Error {
  static STATUS_CODE = 401;
  name = 'AuthenticationError';

  constructor() {
    super('Wrong credentials');
  }
}
```

login.js

```js
import { AuthenticationError, DefaultError } from './errors';

export const login = async (email, password) =>
  axios
    .post('https://conduit.productionready.io/api/users/login', {
      user: {
        email,
        password,
      },
    })
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(error => {
      // Handles the error how you want it
      if (error.status === AuthenticationError.STATUS_CODE) {
        throw new AuthenticationError();
      }
      throw new DefaultError();
    });
```

login.spec.js

```js
import { login } from './login';
import { AuthenticationError, DefaultError } from './errors';

// Mock axios, else you will really request the endpoint
jest.mock('axios');
import axios from 'axios';

describe('Login tests', () => {
  describe('login function', () => {
    const email = 'test@test.com';
    const password = 'password';

    describe('with success', () => {
      const data = { something: {} };

      beforeEach(() => {
        axios.post.mockResolvedValue({ data });
      });

      it('should call endpoint with given email & password', async () => {
        await login(email, password);
        expect(axios.post).toBeCalledWith(
          'https://conduit.productionready.io/api/users/login',
          { user: { email, password } },
        );
      });

      it('should return response data', async () => {
        const response = await login(email, password);
        expect(response).toStrictEqual(data);
      });
    });

    describe('with error', () => {
      describe('status 401', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
          axios.post.mockRejectedValue({ status: 401 });
        });

        it('should throw AuthenticationError', async () => {
          await expect(login(email, password)).rejects.toThrow(AuthenticationError);
        });
      });

      describe('other status', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
          axios.post.mockRejectedValue({});
        });

        it('should throw DefaultError', async () => {
          await expect(login(email, password)).rejects.toThrow(DefaultError);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

We could go further but I think you got the point. Btw, you don't need to split the tests as I did, I just enjoy being able to group the describe by the mocks needed and making little & readable tests.